# On using a string as an integer counter (aka index) in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have a folder with *n* `csv` files. They are accessed and read in a for loop like this:

```
#do stuff
for file in os.listdir(directoryPath):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
       #do stuff
```

Outside of the for loop are a number of `numpy` arrays initialized to zero. Each array has to carry a specific value located in the current `csv` file.

**My question:** is it possible to use `file`, which I assume is a `string`, as an `integer`, in order to fill my arrays for instance like this: `array1[file]=numpy.genfromtxt(file,delimiter=',')[:,2]`?

I am afraid this very line does not work as `file` cannot be treated like an `integer`, so how would you deal with this? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, an index. In my view, `a[file]` should work as `a[i]` but of course `i` was not "declared" in the for loop so I got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), which generates tuples that pair the index of an item with the item itself:

```
for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directoryPath)):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
       array1[i] = numpy.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=',')[:,2]
```

Or you could store the Numpy arrays in a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) that is indexed directly by the associated file name:

```
arrays = {}
for file in os.listdir(directoryPath):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
       arrays[file] = numpy.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=',')[:,2]
```

Or with an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

arrays = OrderedDict()
for file in os.listdir(directoryPath):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
       arrays[file] = numpy.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=',')[:,2]
```

Comment: I assume the resulting `arrays`, if created as `dicts`, will not be sorted smallest to largest in terms of `key`. It's important for me to have them sorted. Should I create a new `for` which sorts the `dicts` or should I make sure their keys are sorted smallest to largest upon filling them? Thanks!

Comment: But since the file names are used as keys, isn't it true that if the former are sorted `event_SMALLEST` to `event_LARGEST`, the latter will automatically follow this order?

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani Python dictionaries are unordered; you can't preserve a given ordering of key/value pairs when storing them in a dictionary.  You can use `OrderedDict` instead, which remembers the order in which you added items (which will be useful if they're sorted already).

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani Alternatively, just use `sorted(arrays)` to get a sorted list of keys, and use them to access the items of `arrays` in order.

Comment: Where exactly should I call the `OrderedDict` in your example with `dicts`? Should I call it upon assigning `arrays[file]`?

Comment: To test the last block I created a folder named "prova" in which there are 3 `csv` files: `file_1.csv`, `file_2.csv`, `file_3.csv`. Each file has a single `int` as value: `1`, `2`, and `3` respectively. How come that the script gets stuck at the `for` line and throws out `IOError: file_1.csv not found. `? If it prints the correct file name, then it should have found it... what is wrong with this?

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani Couldn't say, I'm afraid.  From your description it sounds like it should work.